# Trying to start queue for tracking players turn

Tags: c++, object, queue

I'm trying to start a queue for tracking players turn. There's a possibility of 8 players in the queue, so there should be 8 Player objects in the queue. The error I keep getting is `LNK2005 "public:_thiscall Player::Player(void)" (??0Player@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Main.obj` and also `LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found`. The only answer I found online was to try making my getters inline, but that didn't really help. I also tried making 4 different Player objects without the loop and adding them individually, but that didn't fix anything either. Originally, the Player class was a template class, but I changed it because I didn't think it needed to be one and I was getting a different error when it was. Hopefully someone can give me a heads up as to what I'm doing wrong. The queue is a template though because I wanted to be able to store anything in my queue. So, first I initialized a queue.

```
//initialize players turn in queue
Queue<Player> playerQueue(NUM_PLAYERS);

//track players added
int playerNum = 1;

//keep looping until we reached 
//the number of players
while (playerNum <= NUM_PLAYERS) {

    //create new object
    Player newPlayer;
    //add to queue
    playerQueue.add(newPlayer);
    //increment player count
    playerNum++;
}
```

My player class at the moment is quite simple. The getters are commented out because at the moment they are inlined in the header file. Read that doing so could possibly fix my problem. It did not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "player.h"
#include "queue.h"
using namespace std;

Player::Player() {

    pName = "Outis";
    queuePos = 0;
    propSize = 0;
    currency = 0;
}

//Getters
/*int Player::getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}

int Player::getQueuePos() {
    return queuePos;
}*/
```

This is my header file

```
 class Player {

public:
    Player();

    //Getters
    inline int getCurrency() { return currency; }
    inline int getQueuePos() { return queuePos; }
    //vector<Properties> getProperties();

private:

    //players name
    std::string pName;

    //when it is their turn
    int queuePos;

    //size of property vector
    int propSize;
    //vector to store properties
    //vector<Properties> propList;

    //amount of currency
    int currency;
};
```

This is the add function in my Queue template class

```
// Add value to rear
template<class T>
void Queue<T>::add(const T &val)
{
    if (numStored == capacity)
    {
        cerr << "Queue full: cannot add element" << endl;
        return;
    }

    // add to rear
    int rearIndex = (frontIndex + numStored) % capacity;

    elements[rearIndex] = val;
    numStored++;

}
```

Comment: 1. Remove any variables declared globally in header files.  2. Use *include guards* of some type.  3. Verify that you are not including source files more than once in the build process.  4. Use namespaces.

Comment: Learn to use existing code, such as [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue).  Existing code will save time since it is already debugged for you (nonetheless already written).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I check, there is no globals in header files(unless you're referring to a struct for a Linked List, but I don't think that counts), #ifndef, #define, #endif, are those the include guards you mean? I've got those. I checked my .cpp files, they call their .h files, the main.cpp calls the other .cpp files, that's it. My teacher keeps telling me not to use namespaces, just use "using namespace" You're not the first one to tell me that though. And it still occurs after I changed to use the built-in std::queue. =(

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem...

> I checked my .cpp files, they call their .h files, the main.cpp calls the other .cpp files

had to include the .h files in main, not the .cpp. Don't really understand that because I include the .cpp for the Queue template class I made instead of the .h class. However, the problem is fixed so I'm not touching it. Thanks everyone.